How to resolve ngx-bootstrap Dependency Error
I got the following error, What's the meaning of this error log and do you know how to fix it ? Thanks.
137 error code ERESOLVE
138 error ERESOLVE could not resolve
139 error
140 error While resolving: ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0
140 error Found: @angular/animations@16.2.12
140 error node_modules/@angular/animations
140 error   peer @angular/animations@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from @angular/material@16.2.14
140 error   node_modules/@angular/material
140 error     @angular/material@"^16.2.14" from the root project
140 error   peerOptional @angular/animations@"16.2.12" from @angular/platform-browser@16.2.12
140 error   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
140 error     peer @angular/platform-browser@"16.2.12" from @angular/forms@16.2.12
140 error     node_modules/@angular/forms
140 error       peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from @angular/material@16.2.14
140 error       node_modules/@angular/material
140 error         @angular/material@"^16.2.14" from the root project
140 error       1 more (the root project)
140 error     peer @angular/platform-browser@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from @angular/material@16.2.14
140 error     node_modules/@angular/material
140 error       @angular/material@"^16.2.14" from the root project
140 error     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
140 error   1 more (the root project)
140 error
140 error Could not resolve dependency:
140 error peer @angular/animations@"^17.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0
140 error node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
140 error   ngx-bootstrap@"^12.0.0" from the root project
140 error
140 error Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/animations@17.3.11
140 error node_modules/@angular/animations
140 error   peer @angular/animations@"^17.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0
140 error   node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
140 error     ngx-bootstrap@"^12.0.0" from the root project
140 error
140 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
140 error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
140 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Should i use  --force or --legacy-peer-deps to fix it ? dependency conflict is occurs very often and somehow feel like the library versioning installed like a mess.

See the ngx-bootstrap compatibility table. You are trying to use ngx-bootstrap v12 with Angular v16, but they are not compatible. You now have two options:

Update Angular to v17
Downgrade ngx-bootstrap to v11

The options --force and --legacy-peer-deps should not be used in this case, as you have actual peer dependency conflicts which might lead to problems in your app.
It seems like since v18, the ngx-bootstrap major version now aligns with the Angular major version, so the peer dependency handling should be easier in future.

I have difficulty on reading the error log.  Since the error log is also mention other components as well. How do you know the actually root caused ?

@Suikei the error message is quite verbose. You can check the part starting from "Could not resolve dependency:", this is where you can find details about the conflict. In this case you can see, that ngx-bootstrap expects angular ^17.0.0

It's an issue with the version of Angular and ngx-bootstrap you are using. ngx-bootstrap v12 doesn't seem compatible with Angular 16. You can either upgrade Angular to v17 or downgrade ngx-bootstrap to v11.

I have difficulty on reading the error log.  Since the error log is also mention other components as well. How do you know the actually root caused ?

The other packages mentioned are just default ones that come installed with the angular app (these include animations, platform browser etc)
You'd look at two sections mostly to figure out this version compatibility issue.
140 error While resolving: ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0 140 error Found: @angular/animations@16.2.12 
These two lines say that while the compiler was resolving ngx-bootstrap it found your angular version to be 16.2.12. And later on it mentions the dependency of angular 17 for ngx-bootstrap v12 couldn't be resolved.

let me help you with logs. It says that it can't install ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0 because it found that you already got installed @angular/animations@16.2.12, probably it's in your package.json.
Next it mentions all libs that got dependency on @angular/animations and required versions per each @angular/material@16.2.14 needs @angular/animations@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0", @angular/platform-browser@16.2.12 needs @angular/animations@"16.2.12" etc. Ideally you got to find that one sweet version that satisfy them all, but in that case you got major version conflict and you got to follow our compatibility table as mentioned above.
In the end it concludes that it can't install ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0 because it needs @angular/animations@17.3.11 and it conflicts with your root dependency. Hope your experience with ngx-bootstrap will be pleasant.
